# Remote branch networking

Tags: vpn, rdp, remote-desktop-services

We currently have a remote branch office connecting to the main office through a remote vpn client. Recently we had to upgrade the software application used there. This application talks to the server installed in the main  office through VPN. This setup works fine but the application when connecting to the main office produces a lot of delay which is not acceptible. Before this appliation was a stand alone application and it generates its output in less than few minutes. Now its takes more than 30 minutes. Currently we have a very slow internet connection 1.5mbps/256 kbps with a microsoft vpn client installed on a computer running this application. Our options are

1. Upgrade the internet connection to 20 mbps/800 kbps.
2. Create site to site vpn.
3. Installing this application in a terminal server in the main office and allow users in remote office to rdp to the terminal server through vpn client.

What is the best option?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually do all three, in that order. I assume this is a DSL connection, that uplink is going to seriously nerf your downstream performance. The performance difference you're going to see here will be huge. The small sonicwall firewalls are perfect for getting this done quickly and easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We do already have a modem/router firewall working well. So why should I need a sonicwall firewall? What is the practical efficiency difference between site to site vpn and remote client vpn? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having dedicated hardware to the encryption should speed things up. Any IPSec capable appliance will do, I recommended sonicwall because well, it's easy and fairly secure.